# Haskell "Source reduction"

Tags: haskell, terminology, evaluation, reduction

I'm revising for an upcoming Haskell exam and I don't understand one of the questions on a past paper. Google turns up [nothing useful](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=577&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=haskell+%22source+reduction%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

```
fst(x, y) = x
square i = i * i
```

i) Source reduce, using Haskells lazy evaluation, the expression:

```
fst(square(3+4), square 8)
```

ii) Source reduce, using strict evaluation, the same expression

iii) State one advantage of lazy evaluation and one advantage of strict evaluation

What I don't understand is what *is* source reduction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Reduction** is a term from the lambda calculus which involves a semantics-preserving transformation that replaces one term with an equivalent term.  For the examples you've given, the most important kind of reductions are

- Replacement of a name by its definition (an instance of substituting equals for equals).
- Beta-reduction of a function application.

Beta-reduction is the fundamental rule in the lambda calculus, and in a pure, lazy language like Haskell, it always preserves semantics.  The beta rule is the one that says:

```
(\x. e) m
```

can be replaced by `e` with `m` substituted for `x`.  (The substitution must avoid "capturing" free instances of `x` in `m`.)

It's quite possible that your instructor wants you to combine reductions as follows:

1. Find a function application where the function being applied is a name.
2. Replace the name with its definition, which will be a lambda abstraction.
3. Beta-reduce the application.
4. Do this all in one step.

Notice you often have a *choice* about which application to reduce; for example, in the term you give, there are two applications of `square` and one of `fst` that could be reduced in this fashion.  (The application of + can also be reduced, but reduction involving constants requires different rules.)

From the questions I see that your instructor wants you to **reduce each term repeatedly until it reaches a normal form** and that your instructor wants you to demonstrate your understanding of *different* reduction strategies.  **The word "source" in "source reduce" is superfluous;** reduction *means* manipulation of source terms in some language.  I would have phrased the questions as follows:

- Using the reduction strategy that corresponds to Haskell's lazy evaluation, reduce the following expression to weak head normal form.  Show each step in the sequence of reductions.
- Using the reduction strategy that corresponds to evaluation in a strict functional language, reduce the following expression to head normal form.

I probably would have chosen to be less coy and just name the reduction strategies: a call-by-need reduction strategy and a call-by-value reduction strategy.

Answer (score 7):

From the structure of the question, it ***probably*** just mean "evaluate the expression by hand", e.g.

```
head (map primeTest (enumFromTo 1000 2000))
```

in lazy (evaluate only when needed) evaluation,

```
  head (map primeTest (enumFromTo 1000 2000))
= head (map primeTest (1000 : enumFromTo 1001 2000))
= head (primeTest 1000 : map primeTest (enumFromTo 1001 2000))
= primeTest 1000
= False
```

in strict (evaluate everything first) evaluation

```
  head (map primeTest (enumFromTo 1000 2000))
= head (map primeTest (1000 : enumFromTo 1001 2000))
= ...
= head (map primeTest [1000, 1001, ..., 2000])
= head (primeTest 1000 : map primeTest [1001, 1002, ..., 2000])
= head (False : map primeTest [1001, 1002, ..., 2000])
= ...
= head [False, False, ..., False]
= False
```

The only relevant place I could find is http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/modules/2009/11582.html where "source reducation" is listed as a "Programming technique". (O_O)

Comment: I wish he'd just say that in the paper, "evaluate this" would have made a lot more sense!

Comment: @The notes you found: I study CS at Birmingham, those are the notes for the module I took. I do love lecturers who just make things up.